# Does Angular's $compile method scan the entire DOM?

Tags: angularjs

Can someone tell me. Does calling $compile cause angular to traverse the entire DOM? I read somewhere that compiling is an expensive task as it requires angular to traverse the DOM looking for directives, so calling it many times can slow things down. But I can't find where I read it now.

I would like to know if I did the following would it just compile the markup or
would it also force angular to scan the entire DOM?

```
$compile(<div>{{name}}</div>)(scope);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the $compile service only evaluates the nodes that you pass to it.  You can see this in the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L810.  It does not need to evaluate the entire DOM to compile the nodes that you have passed to it.